# Как добиться эффекта кипы бумаг на css?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[image]

Привет, блок резиновый, может быть разной длинны и\или высоты.
Думал обойтись псевдоэлементами, но их невозможно подсунуть под главный блок.

Помогите отыскать наиболее верное решение?

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.un__shadow {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
}
.un__shadow:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.un__shadow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
```

```html
<div class="un__shadow">
  <h1>Some details</h1>
  <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
```

Вот фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/Unk4N/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Думал обойтись псевдоэлементами, но их
>   невозможно подсунуть под главный блок.

Кто вам такое сказал?

```css
#custom, #custom::before, #custom::after {    
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

#custom {
    background: #c3c3c3;
    position: relative;
}

#custom::before, #custom::after {
    background: #ffffff;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}

#custom::before {
    bottom: -7px;
    right: -7px;
    z-index: -2;
}

#custom::after {
    bottom: -4px;
    right: -4px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  

<div id="custom">
    <h1>Some details</h1>
    <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/ELaeH/1/)

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь корректно показывает контент в первом блоке.

Comment: Примного благодарю Вас!!!

Comment: @Arhad пожалуйста, не удаляйте ссылки на JSFiddle из моих ответов.

Comment: @VenZell, понял, больше не буду. На правах чистого любопытства: почему?

Comment: @Arhad, просто непорядок: "не так лежало". :) Спасибо за понимание и желание помочь ресурсу, я это очень ценю.

Comment: @Arhad, потому что на jsfiddle любой может поэкспериментировать с кодом. А со сниппетом эта возможность ограничена.

Comment: @Qwertiy, после нажатия кнопки _копировать код в ответ_ можно экспериментировать с кодом сниппета в своем ответе

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vertigo/kcxmY/

Comment: Может проще использовать before и after?

Comment: поддерживаю. тоже так бы сделал

Comment: Может и проще. Опишите этот метод, для меня тоже будет опыт.

Comment: http://www.webmasters.by/articles/html-coding/1187-before-and-after-in-css.html
Вот тут можно посмотреть похожую штуку